# Mongodb concat int and string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to project FileName and FileSize for all my files in my collection with a size of 50 mb and greater, but I cannot concat a the type FileSize as it has a type of Int

I want the projection to be

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b6308"),
        "FileName" : "1234567890.xml",
        "FileSize" : "11.06 MB"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b630f"),
        "FileName" : "2468101214.xml",
        "FileSize" : "320.48 MB"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b631f"),
        "FileName" : "3691215180.xml",
        "FileSize" : "12.95 MB"
    }
}
```

But so far I can Only return the following

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b6308"),
        "FileName" : "1234567890.xml",
        "FileSize" : 11.0610504150390630
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b630f"),
        "FileName" : "2468101214.xml",
        "FileSize" : 320.4827098846435500
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b631f"),
        "FileName" : "3691215180.xml",
        "FileSize" : 12.9519605636596680
    }
}
```

My query:

```
    db.MyCollection.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $match: {
      FileSize: {$gte: 5000000}
      }
    },
    // Stage 2
    {
      $project: {
        FileName: 1,
        FileSize: {$divide: ["$FileSize", 1048576]}
      }
    },
    // Stage 3
    {
        $project:{
            FileName:1,
            FileSize:{$concat:["$FileSize", "MB"]}
        }
     }
```

How do I concat the FileSize and "MB" field?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The trick here is to use [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) to do the conversion to a string, and a few little extras to handle the decimal point precision:

```js
    { "$project": {
        "FileName": 1,
        "FileSize": {
            "$concat": [
                { "$substr": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$FileSize", { "$mod": [ "$FileSize", 1 ] }]},
                    0,
                    -1
                ]},
                { "$substr": [ { "$mod": [ "$FileSize", 1 ] }, 1, 3] },
                " MB",
            ]
        }
    }}
```

Or better yet, combine into a single `$project`, either with the help of [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) in versions later than MongoDB 2.6, or in long for if needed. A single pipeline stage is more efficient than two:

```js
    { "$project": {
        "FileName": 1,
        "FileSize": {
            "$let": {
                "vars": {
                    "FileSize": { "$divide": [ "$FileSize", 1048576 ] }
                },
                "in":{
                    "$concat": [
                        { "$substr": [
                            { "$subtract": [ "$$FileSize", { "$mod": [ "$$FileSize", 1 ] }]},
                            0,
                            -1
                        ]},
                        { "$substr": [ { "$mod": [ "$$FileSize", 1 ] }, 1, 3] },
                        " MB",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

So as long as you break up the number at the decimal point ( via [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) ) you can throw a "length" argument to the rest of the string to deal with numbers of arbitary length. With the "remainder" separated from the use of `$mod` the length of the string to two decimal places is always "three", starting of course from the second position in order to skip the leading `0`.

Returns exactly what you asked for:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b6308"),
        "FileName" : "1234567890.xml",
        "FileSize" : "11.06 MB"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b630f"),
        "FileName" : "2468101214.xml",
        "FileSize" : "320.48 MB"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5652c399a21dad0bb01b631f"),
        "FileName" : "3691215180.xml",
        "FileSize" : "12.95 MB"
}
```

Comment: The `$toString` operator was added meanwhile: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/. See below for an answer explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 39):

Add Stage 2.5 :P

```
{
    $project:{
        FileName:1,
            FileSize:{$substr:["$FileSize", 0, -1 ]}
    }
}
```

FileSize is a integer and there is no operation to convert it to String. So you can use hack, and use substr to convert it to string, 0 for starting and -1 rest of the string.

Comment: The `$toString` operator was added meanwhile: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/. See below for an answer explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 20):

It is possible now in MongoDB v4.0 using [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) operator which converts a value to a string:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            FileSize: { $concat: [ { $toString: "$FileSize" }, " MB" ] }
        }
    }
])
```