# Aggregate Conversion String to Int to with Mongo 3.2.9

Tags: mongodb

The issue I have is making a conversion from a string to an integer in order to create an average. I know to use the $convert in later versions, but I cannot find the correct place to use the $toInt term. I know the conversion using this keyword works on the command line on a single example, but where should I place this within the aggregate framework.

```
db.my_batch.aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$current.Data.x" },
{ "$match": { "current.Data.x.Typ": "01", "current.Data.x.Value": { "$lt": "TTTT" } } },
{ "$project": { "current.Data.x.Value": 1, "uId": 1 } },
{ "$group": { "_id": null, "ad": { "$avg": { "$toInt": "$current.Data.x.Value" } } } }]
)
```

I get the following response:

```
2018-07-20T17:19:42.707+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$toInt'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed :
```

Comment: `$toInt` was added in 4.0 along with `$convert`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK for simple cases on 3.2.9 I can execute this: > $toInt: "1"
1. However now when I check the other keywords examples, we find: $toInt: "1.6777" gives 1.6777. No error, but simply does not function as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you have a 4.0 Mongo shell, but an old server? Why don't you upgrade your server to the latest version? It has a bunch of security and performance enhancements too!

Comment: You may want to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413303/2724342

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $toInt and $convert operators were only added in mongodb 4.0, it is best for you to change field type in database and query after that.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to convert int to string (the opposite of OP's question).

I'm posting this answer here in case it helps someone. OP wanted [`$toInt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/), but I needed the opposite; [`$toString`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/#mongodb-expression-exp.-toString)  and/or [`$convert`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#example), but those are too new (MongoDB 4.0)

You [can use `$substr` as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string):

```
...
{ stringifiedInt: { $substr: ['$intProperty', 0, -1] } }
...
```

If you are looking to convert int to text, consider other options here [which is very similar  - Use Javascript on query results to `.forEach` and/or `.map` your results (but then you can't do aggregations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb/52413303#52413303)

You could:

- Use [complicated (but cool) string-to-number parsing aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413303/1175496)
- [Change the value stored in DB from string to NumberInt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29490567/1175496), so your query works
- Use Javascript on query results to `.forEach` and/or `.map` your results (but then you can't do aggregations)