# Mongoose group by field and grouped result should be stored as groupname: object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For the following Schema (pseudo code).

```
new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {type: String, unique: true},
      foo: {type: Number},
      bar: {type: Number, default: null},
}
```

Normal Result would be .find():

```
[{
    _id: x
    name: 'Name1'
    foo: 1
    bar: 222
}, {
    _id: y
    name: 'Name2'
    foo: 1
    bar: 333
}, {
    _id: z
    name: 'Name3'
    foo: 2
    bar: 444
}];
```

I want return results grouped by foo and the the key should be the variable/number of foo:

```
[{
    '1': [{
        name: 'Name1'
        bar: 222
    }, {
        name: 'Name2'
        bar: 333
    }],
    '2': [{
        name: 'Name3'
        bar: 444
    }]
}]
```

I was trying that with aggregate, but i were never able to replace _id with the the 'Number of Foo'.

Is this even possible with mongoose? Or do i need to edit the object within a Nodejs function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$foo",
            obj: { $push: { name: "$name", bar: "$bar" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { obj: [ { k: {$substr:["$_id", 0, -1 ]}, v: "$obj" } ] },
                    in: { $arrayToObject: "$$obj" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "2" : [ { "name" : "Name3", "bar" : 444 } ] }
{ "1" : [ { "name" : "Name1", "bar" : 222 }, { "name" : "Name2", "bar" : 333 } ] }
```

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) allows you to define new object on root level. To dynamically create keys you need [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) which takes an array of k-v pairs (defined using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) here). To convert int to string you can use a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string) with `$substr` (`{$substr:["$foo", 0, -1 ]}`) or [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) operator in MongoDB v 4.0

Comment: It doesn't group the foo Numbers.

Current output would be: [{'1': {name: 'string', bar: 123}},{'1': {name: 'string2', bar: 456}}]. But it should be: [{'1': [{name: 'string', bar: 123}},{name: 'string2', bar: 456]}]

Comment: @end I assume that foo Numbers are grouped and you just want to transform the output so my pipeline stage should be added after `$group`

Comment: Normal result is just the clean .find() output. I've tried before with
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$foo',
                    foo: {
                        $push: '$$ROOT'
                    }
                }
            },

but getting error then: "can't convert from BSON type array to String"

Comment: Could you edit your question and add sample data with expected result ? That would make it  easier to help. Thanks

Comment: added wanted example result.

Comment: thank you, but this is not working well. it's now:  [{'1': {name: [{name: 'name1'}]}}]
it's an object with propertie name instead of array => object after '1'

Comment: should be fine now

Comment: thank you very much mickl, that is indeed working. Looks like i have to learn alot more about mongo and aggregate.

Comment: how can we add another key from different document ?