# Mongodb while aggregate group value as key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was trying to aggregate and group values but want one of the field as key.

```
[
  {id:1, value: "x"},
  {id:2, value: "y"},
  {id:1, value: "a"},
  {id:2, value: "b"},
]
```

used this query but no luck

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$id",
            "value": {$push: "$$ROOT" }
        } 
    }
])
```

Was trying to achieve this

```
[
 { 1:[x,a] },
 { 2:[y,b] }
]
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) twice to get single document which contains an array of `k,v` pairs. Then you can run [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) on that document along with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote new object into root level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$id",
            values: { $push: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            root: { $push: { k: { $toString: "$_id" }, v: "$values" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: "$root"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HadarVBHh4f)

Comment: It worked thanks a lot, but need to update my db version to 4.0. to make $toString to work.

Comment: @ashokk or you can check the workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string