# How to get percentage total of data with group by date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to get percentage total of data with group by date in MongoDB ?

Link example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/aNND4EPQhcb

I have some collection structure like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4b"), 
    "date" : "2019-05-03T10:39:53.108Z",  
    "id" : 166,   
    "update_at" : "2019-05-03T10:45:36.208Z",  
    "type" : "image"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4c"), 
    "date" : "2019-05-03T10:39:53.133Z",  
    "id" : 166,   
    "update_at" : "2019-05-03T10:45:36.208Z", 
    "type" : "image"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4d"), 
    "date" : "2019-05-03T10:39:53.180Z", 
    "id" : 166,  
    "update_at" : "2019-05-03T10:45:36.208Z", 
    "type" : "image"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4e"), 
    "date" : "2019-05-03T10:39:53.218Z",  
    "id" : 166,  
    "update_at" : "2019-05-03T10:45:36.208Z",  
    "type" : "image"
}
```

And I have query in mongodb to get data of collection, how to get percentage of total data. in bellow example query to get data :

```
db.name_collection.aggregate(
   [
        { "$match": {  
            "update_at": { "$gte": "2019-11-04T00:00:00.0Z", "$lt": "2019-11-06T00:00:00.0Z"},
             "id": { "$in": [166] } 
        } },  
        {
           "$group" : { 
               "_id": {
                       $substr: [ '$update_at', 0, 10 ] 
                },
               "count" : {
                   "$sum" : 1
               } 
           }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : 0,
                "date" : "$_id",
                "count" : "$count" 
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "date" : 1
            }
        }
   ]
)
```

and this response :

```
{ 
    "date" : "2019-11-04", 
    "count" : 39
},
{ 
    "date" : "2019-11-05", 
    "count" : 135
}
```

how to get percentage data total from key count ? example response to this :

```
{ 
    "date" : "2019-11-04", 
    "count" : 39,
    "percentage" : "22%"
},
{ 
    "date" : "2019-11-05", 
    "count" : 135,
    "percentage" : "78%"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group by `null` to get `total` count and then use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to calculate the percentage. [$round](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/) will be a useful operator in such case. Finally you can [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get back the same number of documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // previous aggregation steps
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: { $sum: "$count" },
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            docs: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$docs",
                    in: {
                        date: "$$this.date",
                        count: "$$this.count",
                        percentage: { $concat: [ { $toString: { $round: { $multiply: [  { $divide: [ "$$this.count", "$total" ] }, 100 ] } } }, '%' ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$docs"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r7Fsfq3oLN0)

Comment: I think what I mean is to get a way after "group by date then add the total precentage" to note how after group by date. can see my sample collection again?

Comment: @MiftachHidayatullah your aggregation is totally fine, you just need to add more stages to existing code, that's why I left this comment (// previous aggregation steps) to indicate that my stages are the continuation of your pipeline

Comment: @MiftachHidayatullah considering your example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KEB4d58q0OD

Comment: i have try that, but show error "mongodb unrecognized expression '$tostring'", is this mongodb version problem?

Comment: Yes, you need to upgrade to `4.0` or higher

Comment: @MiftachHidayatullah you can also try this old workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string

Comment: okey, btw i wanna ask again for others case, this https://mongoplayground.net/p/6B-y7CB2K2L . how to show other hours is data 0 ?

Comment: example result this :

[
  {
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "01"
  },
 {
    "count": 2,
    "hour": "02"
  },
{
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "03"
  },
{
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "04"
  },
{
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "05"
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "hour": "20"
  }
]

and etc

Comment: @MiftachHidayatullah can you open a separate question ?