# How to group data by every hour

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I get counts data grouped by every hour in 24 hours even if data is not present i.e. IF 0 will select 0

MonogDB 3.6

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4b"),
    "date": "2019-05-03T10:39:53.108Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-05-03T02:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4c"),
    "date": "2019-05-03T10:39:53.133Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-05-03T02:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced4d"),
    "date": "2019-05-03T10:39:53.180Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-05-03T20:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced7a"),
    "date": "2019-05-10T10:39:53.218Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-12-04T10:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2ced7b"),
    "date": "2019-05-03T10:39:53.108Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-05-05T10:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2cedae"),
    "date": "2019-05-03T10:39:53.133Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-05-05T10:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2cedad"),
    "date": "2019-05-03T10:39:53.180Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-05-06T10:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ccbb96706d1d47a4b2cedab"),
    "date": "2019-05-10T10:39:53.218Z",
    "id": 166,
    "update_at": "2019-12-06T10:45:36.208Z",
    "type": "image"
  }
]
```

**Implementation**

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    update_at: {
      "$gte": "2019-05-03T00:00:00.0Z",
      "$lt": "2019-05-05T00:00:00.0Z"
    },
    id: {
      "$in": [
        166
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      $substr: [
        "$update_at",
        11,
        2
      ]
    },
    count: {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  },

},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    hour: "$_id",
    count: "$count"
  }
},
{
  $sort: {
    hour: 1
  }
})
```

**Actual Output**:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "hour": "02"
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "hour": "20"
  }
```

My expectation code show 24 hours event data is 0 or null and convert from example "02" as "02 AM" , "13" as "01 PM":

**Expected Output**

```
  {
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "01" // 01 AM
  },
  {
    "count": 2,
    "hour": "02"
  },
  {
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "03"
  },
  {
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "04"
  },
  {
    "count": 0,
    "hour": "05"
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "hour": "20" // to 08 pm
  }
```

Comment: Why on earth do you store date values as string rather than proper `Date` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

### Explanation

We group by hour to count how many images are uploaded.

Then, we add extra field `hour` to create time interval (if you had v4.x, there is a better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb)).

We flattern `hour` field (will create new documents) and split first 2 digits to match `count` and split last 2 digits to put AM / PM periods.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      update_at: {
        "$gte": "2019-05-03T00:00:00.0Z",
        "$lt": "2019-05-05T00:00:00.0Z"
      },
      id: {
        "$in": [
          166
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $substr: [
          "$update_at",
          11,
          2
        ]
      },
      count: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      hour: [
        "0000",
        "0101",
        "0202",
        "0303",
        "0404",
        "0505",
        "0606",
        "0707",
        "0808",
        "0909",
        "1010",
        "1111",
        "1212",
        "1301",
        "1402",
        "1503",
        "1604",
        "1705",
        "1806",
        "1907",
        "2008",
        "2109",
        "2210",
        "2311"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$hour"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      hour: 1,
      count: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $substr: [
                  "$hour",
                  0,
                  2
                ]
              },
              "$_id"
            ]
          },
          "$count",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$hour",
      count: {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      hour: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $substr: [
              "$_id",
              2,
              2
            ]
          },
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $substr: [
                      "$_id",
                      0,
                      2
                    ]
                  },
                  "12"
                ]
              },
              " PM",
              " AM"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      count: "$count"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/obck4zDHVN2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output in Indian Time formate. then below code work!

```
    const query = [
    {
        $match: {
            update_at: {
                "$gte": ISODate("2019-05-03T00:00:00.0Z"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2019-05-05T00:00:00.0Z")
            },
            id: {
                "$in": [
                    166
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "h": { "$hour": { date: "$update_at", timezone: "+0530" } },
        }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: { $hour: "$h" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: this query test in mongodb 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you can test it out, for MongoDB 4.0+

i will be improving query and update

```
const query = [{
    $match: {
        update_at: {
            "$gte": ISODate("2019-05-03T00:00:00.0Z"),
            "$lt": ISODate("2019-05-05T00:00:00.0Z")
        },
        id: {
            "$in": [
                166
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: { $hour: "$update_at" },
        count: {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    },

},

{
    $addFields: {
        hourStr: { $toString: { $cond: { if: { $gte: ["$_id", 12] }, then: { $subtract: [12, { $mod: [24, '$_id'] }] }, else: "$_id" } } },
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        formated: { $concat: ["$hourStr", { $cond: { if: { $gt: ["$_id", 12] }, then: " PM", else: " AM" } }] },
        count: "$count",
        hour: 1,
    }
}]
```

Comment: Nooo, cant running your query cause my mongodb server version is 3.* :(

Comment: "Unrecognized expression $toInt"

Answer (score 0):

There's no "magic" solution, you'll have to hardcode it into your aggregation:

Heres an example using Mongo v3.2+ syntax with some [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) magic:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            update_at: {
                "$gte": "2019-05-03T00:00:00.0Z",
                "$lt": "2019-05-05T00:00:00.0Z"
            },
            id: {"$in": [166]}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$substr: ["$update_at", 11, 2]},
            count: {"$sum": 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            hours: {$push: {hour: "$_id", count: "$count"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            hours: {
                $map: {
                    input: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                            "$hours",
                            {
                                $map: {
                                    input: {
                                        $filter: {
                                            input: ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"],
                                            as: "missingHour",
                                            cond: {
                                                $not: {
                                                    $in: [
                                                        "$$missingHour",
                                                        {
                                                            $map: {
                                                                input: "$hours",
                                                                as: "hourObj",
                                                                in: "$$hourObj.hour"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    as: "missingHour",
                                    in: {hour: "$$missingHour", count: 0}
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    as: "hourObject",
                    in: {
                        count: "$$hourObject.count",
                        hour: {
                            $cond: [
                                {$eq: [{$substr: ["$$hourObject.hour", 0, 1]}, "0"]},
                                {$concat: ["$$hourObject.hour", " AM"]},
                                {
                                    $concat: [{
                                        $switch: {
                                            branches: [
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "13"]}, then: "1"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "14"]}, then: "2"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "15"]}, then: "3"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "16"]}, then: "4"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "17"]}, then: "5"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "18"]}, then: "6"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "19"]}, then: "7"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "20"]}, then: "8"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "21"]}, then: "9"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "22"]}, then: "10"},
                                                {case: {$eq: ["$$hourObject.hour", "23"]}, then: "11"},
                                            ],
                                            default: "None"
                                        }
                                    }, " PM"]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$hours"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            hour: "$hours.hour",
            count: "$hours.count"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            hour: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

A short explanation of the `$addFields` stage: we first add hours that we're missing, we then merge the two arrays (of the original found hours and the "new" missing hours), finally we convert to the required output ("01" to "01 AM").

If you're using Mongo v4+ I recommend you change the `$group` `_id` stage to use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) as its more consistent.

```
_id: {$hour: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$update_at"}}}
```

If you do do that, you'll have to update the `$filter` and `$map` section to use numbers and not strings and eventually using [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) to cast into the format you want, hence the v4+ requirement.

Comment: this response hours for 12 > is 13,14,etc . i want to 13 is 1 pm,etc. how about it?

Comment: Are you on Mongo version 4.0+ ? if so just change the final condition in the `$addFields` stage to cast to Integer and substract 12.

Comment: No, my mongo version is 3.* :(

Comment: Then you will have to hardcode the conversion. similar to what i just did with the hours

Comment: Ok To, I'll wait it

Comment: I added a `$switch` at the end of the `$addFields` stage, to convert it to the required format.

Answer (score 0):

You should store date values as `Date` objects instead of strings. I would do the formatting like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { $match: { ... } },
      {
         $group: {
            _id: { h: { $hour: "$update_at" } },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
      },
      {
         $project: {
            _id: 0,
            hour: {
               $switch: {
                  branches: [
                     { case: { $lt: ["$_id.h", 10] }, then: { $concat: ["0", { $toString: "$_id.h" }, " AM"] } },
                     { case: { $lt: ["$_id.h", 13] }, then: { $concat: [{ $toString: "$_id.h" }, " AM"] } },
                     { case: { $lt: ["$_id.h", 22] }, then: { $concat: ["0", { $toString: { $subtract: ["$_id.h", 12] } }, " PM"] } },
                     { case: { $lt: ["$_id.h", 24] }, then: { $concat: [{ $toString: { $subtract: ["$_id.h", 12] } }, " PM"] } }
                  ]
               }
            },
            hour24: "$_id.h",
            count: 1
         }
      },
      { $sort: { hour24: 1 } }
   ])
```

As non-American I am not familiar with AM/PM rules, esp. for midnight and midday but I guess you get the principle.

Comment: Hi Dom, my version mongodb server is 3.*, can't use $toString. "Unrecognized expression '$toString"

Comment: Perhaps simply skip it. Without I get *"$concat only supports strings, not int"*. Otherwise there seems to be a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string